# How to expire the password reset token

Tags: c#, vb.net, passwords

I am trying to implement reset password functionality in my ASP.Net MVC-5 Project. So for reset token I have used one random token generator. And I am emailing the token to the user but after saving the token in the database I want the token to get expired after certain period of time. I googled but much to my surprise I could not find something concrete. So, can some one guide me on how to implement expiry of token from database or is there any other way to achieve it. I am a beginner so I don't know much. Either C# or VB.Net anything will do. Do, I need stored procedure or trigger or something. just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store timestamp when token was sent and check this timestamp when user will try reset password. If timestamp is too old - ask to request new reset token.

Comment: I prefer to store an expires time, but it's the same thing in the end. Also, the reset token now has the ability to stand in for a password. If the database is comprised in a read-only way, most tokens will have expired, but some may still be good. Thus the token should be stored with similar security to password storage: don't store the token directly; store a hash of the token.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a job in the database. That way you can set a time and it will run as often as you want